# How to implement in the cake PHP for Nested tags?

Tags: cakephp

I wanna know how to do the CakePHP code for,

```
<a href="#">Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a>
```

The Icon is not visible in the output page (I Don't know the correct method).

If I give as `<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send">Send</a>` the font changes obviously and the icon comes to the front and text goes after that.

So, please give me a solution, Guys !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Arun try this one ..

```
                echo $this->Html->link(
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>',
                    '#',
                    array(
                     'escape' => false,
                    )
                 );
```